# android background issue

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with my background. Depending on my manifest settings I either have the background being squished when i bring up a soft keyboard like this:

[image]

Or else I get this with the graphics being pushed off the screen:
[image]

If I tap the black area the graphics come down, but now the EditText is pushed down like this: 
[image]

How do I fix this? The top should always look like the last image, but I should always see the edittext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on if you have room in your layout to shrink things.  The keyboard comes up in 1 of two modes, set in android:winowSoftInputMode of your activity.

- Pan-  the app is moved to ensure the focused edit text remains on
  screen (or at least the cursor's area does).
- Resize-  the app is resized to fit the screen.  This means that
  things are srunk, if possible.  Of course the only things that can be
  shrunk are items with a height of fill_parent.  If it can't resize
  the app and make it work, things will be moved offscreen

**It will do one of those two things.  It looks to me like you have too much in your UI to resize, except squishing the top.  In that case, you'll scroll.  The problem is that when the user taps the black area, that area is getting focused.  So Android pans to make that area on screen.  It will not even attempt to make sure stuff below it stays on screen.**

In other words, there isn't much you can do.

Comment: can I change to a background image that is different when the keyboard is up? Everything is fine apart from the background image. IE, when my background image was all just a plain one colour background everything works fine, as it looks consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the `onCreate` method of your activity. This is a quick fix.

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

And you should also check.

`android:windowSoftInputMode` this basically handles a lot of issues about the softkeyboard in android.

---Edit---

[Soft Keyboard](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) This stuff is helpful for you then.

Comment: doesnt help im afraid, same thing happens

Comment: Afraid it doesn't help, that is getting squished like mine :(